# How can we achive gridview paging incremented by configured amount

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, gridview, pagination

I am facing challenges while implementing this functionality in gridview in which I need to show 15 pages first and after than it should increment by 5 only
i.e. 1. 1 to 15
     2. 6 to 20 etc.

In the pagersetting I don't find any option which increment it by some configured page extension nummber so how can I achieve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Gridview Custom paging using Stored Procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595611/how-to-implement-gridview-custom-paging-using-stored-procedure)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961844/asp-net-how-to-create-a-custom-pager-for-gridview

Comment: My requirement is different as if I click on 15th record it should get advanced by 5

Comment: Have you tried something that we can help you debug? Some of us get paid to produce code to meet requirements like this, and you're asking for code for free.